.onMove function does not work properly in iOS 16.0
I have a problem with the .onMove function. I believe I have set everything up properly. However, the moving does not seem to be working correctly. When I try to move the item, it is highlighted first, as it is supposed to be. Then, while I am moving it through the list, it disappears for some reason, and at the end of the move, it comes back to its initial place. (I use iOS 16.0 minimum, so I don't have to include the EditButton(). It works the same in the edit mode tho)
import SwiftUI

struct Animal: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct ListMove: View {
    
    @State var animals = [Animal(name: "Dog"), Animal(name: "Cat"), Animal(name: "Cow"), Animal(name: "Goat"), Animal(name: "Chicken")]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(animals) { animal in
                Text(animal.name)
            }
            .onMove(perform: move)
        }
    }
    
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        animals.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
    
}

#Preview {
    ListMove()
}



For your info, your code works well for me on iOS-18 (real devices).
Note I cannot test it on iOS 16.

Minimum Deployment iOS 16, but which SDK and are you testing on Simulator or physical device?

There is an issue with the preview. Run it on your device and everything will work perfectly well!

Well, previews are not real simulators, they are just a quick look system.
